# cont.se não funciona no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma coluna no Excel com 38 linhas. Dentro delas há duas palavras: **Amarela** e **Branca**, quero fazer uma contagem de quantas vezes essas palavras foram informadas.
Utilizei a seguinte fórmula:

```
=cont.se(A1:A38;"Branca")
```

Porém, não funcionou, o que há de errado?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só retorna **#NAME?**

Comment: retorna o mesmo erro

Comment: uso a versão Excel 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro `#NAME` indica que o Excel não conseguiu identificar determinada parte da fórmula. Ao invés de [`CONT.SE`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/CONTSE-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) use [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34?CorrelationId=c3599071-336c-4343-b03f-a868ee0bf107&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) se você estiver usando a versão em inglês.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A38;"Branca")
```

Comment: Tentei apenas com a `,` e o Excel nem aceitou.

Comment: o meu Excel está em inglês, de qualquer forma eu tentei e não foi.

Comment: Funcionou! Só que ao invés de `,` o correto é `;`.

Comment: Estou tentando esse comando =CONtar.se(D4:D200;"Motor") mas da erro, como seria em portugues?

Comment: Conseui resolver usei esse comando =CONT.SE(D4:D200;"motor")